# Having a problem with my github navbar menu toggle

Tags: javascript, github, navbar

Iam coding my company website and i decided to host it in github. My problem may feel some confusing. I coded my navbar and added a menu toggle button when the website is opened in a mobile. When I hosted my website in 000webhost the toggle button works perfectly. But when hosted in github the toggle doesn't works. So I think that github doesn't support that. But later I am confused that when I opened my website hosted in github in my phone's inbuilt browser it worked. The thing is it is not working in google chrome and other browser, but works perfectly in my built in browser.

Link to my github page: https://github.com/TaakloCommunity/TaakloCommunity.github.io

please help me with correct explanation.

Comment: Check errors in the browser console :)

Comment: I undertsand it. The browser console is showing error in jquery place. Is there any other way to upload jquery in github pages.

Comment: I believe you can just change http to https in jquery cdn url